# Scan local web server for devices

Tags: c#, networking, webserver, lan, gateway

A friend asked me this, so please don't mind if the question looks stupid:

Given is local network IP address

User wants to scan the server with that address for anything with a Web control, i.e printers / routers / phones etc

Any idea if this is possible and with which programing language ?

Note: User is inside LAN

Comment: While logged in to the server or remotely? This is very broad "if its possible".

Comment: User is inside LAN

Comment: So RDP"d on or remote? I'm not asking a 3rd time

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but wouldn't this work by making a socket connection to certain ports and see if the host replies? Afaik there is no 'broadcast' port to scan for active ports, I think you'd have to code-in to try different ports within a specific range and see if they are active?